# Angular: pre-select from Rest-ful Service

Tags: angularjs

I´d like to pre-select a select-field from a given Restful-Service:

```
$scope.findOne = function () {

        $scope.teams = Teams.query();

        $scope.teamCategory = TeamCategories.get({
            teamCategoryId: $stateParams.teamCategoryId
        });
    };
```

This is my function to get one Team-Category from my database.

```
<select name="assignedTeams" size="10" id="assignedTeams" multiple class="form-control" data-ng-model="teamCategory.assignedTeams" ng-options="team._id as team.detailName for team in teams" required>
                                <option value="">Please choose.</option>
                            </select>
```

and this is my select-Field. Both Services return the correct results, I can see them in the console. But the select-Field is not pre-selected. Where is my fault?

Comment: not sure this is the correct way but 
i presume you get an array from Rest. so you could do something like this `$scope.teamCategory.assignedTeams = teams[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make $scope.teamCategory.assignedTeams be an array that only contains the team ids you want to select.  It should look like the following:

```
$scope.teamCategory.assignedTeams = [1,2,3];
```

The values 1, 2, 3 should be the teams ids you want selected.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. The Restful-Service should not populate the response - then the selectFields are correctly set.

Thanks to your help!